# SqlDependency.OnChange doesn't fire

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldependency

I am currenty making an application for my university project. App should send out some form of notification via email after changes in the database.

There is an `.mdf` file of database to which I connect with `(localdb)`, viewing and editing done with dataset tables and `SQLDataAdapter`s (if it matters or not, I don't know). I am trying to setup `SqlDependency` so it performs checks on table for new flags so it could sent email about rows with those flags.

The problem is that I can't make `sqlDependency.OnChange` event to trigger, `Service Broker` is enabled. After I boot the app, I start `SqlDependency`, after that I edit and save data in one of my `SqlAdapter` methods, data changes in database (in mdf file), but no event triggers. I tried multiple tutorials and none seem to work for me.  Here's the code:

```
 public void StartWatching()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(con.ConnectionString);
        SqlDependency.Start(con.ConnectionString);
        ExecuteWatchingQuery();
    }

    private void ExecuteWatchingQuery()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(
                "select [id], [subject] from dbo.lots", connection))
            {
                var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                sqlDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDatabaseChange);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    Log_Text.AppendText("Watching... \n");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log_Text.AppendText("No rows found.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDatabaseChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs args)
    {[enter image description here][1]
        SqlNotificationInfo info = args.Info;
        if (SqlNotificationInfo.Insert.Equals(info)
            || SqlNotificationInfo.Update.Equals(info)
            || SqlNotificationInfo.Delete.Equals(info))
        {
            Log_Text.AppendText("Saw changes: \n");
            Watching();
        }
        ExecuteWatchingQuery();
    }
```

Source: http://ts-soft.ru/blog/mssql-database-watching

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyBOf.png  The table

Comment: Everything looks correct. What does return the following query `SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'database_name'?`

Comment: Broker is enabled, query return `1`. I moved my app to the server to get rid of `localdb`, still doesn't respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the fact, that both editing and monitoring were done in the same app, I'm not sure if not on the same connection. I devided app into two (one - database editing, other - console app for monitoring), and all started working.